# Display data from database inside <table> using wordpress $wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress, html-table

Can someone help me, how to code the logic to print the data from my database into a `<table>`?

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
     <th>Firstname</th>
     <th>Lastname</th>
     <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM myTable" );
        foreach ( $result as $print )   {
            echo '<td>' $print->firstname.'</td>';
            }
      ?>
    </tr>               
</table>
```

[image: table]

I know this is so basic, but I'm having a hard time making this work.

Comment: you're missing `.` in `echo '<td>' $print->firstname.'</td>';`

Comment: Also, you should always use `htmlspecialchars()` when appending text to HTML.

Comment: hi @rid can you explain to me what `htmlspecialhchars()` do? the PHP manual is too technical to understand. thanks.

Comment: @user1933824, basically it replaces characters such a `<` and `>` with the HTML necessary for displaying those characters. For example, if the first name is "<bill>", then the resulting HTML without `htmlspecialchars()` will be `<bill>`, which is a tag and won't display. `htmlspecialchars()` replaces that with `&lt;bill&gt;`.

Comment: Where do you execute that code in wordpress???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th>Firstname</th>
 <th>Lastname</th>
 <th>Points</th>
</tr>
  <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM myTable" );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $print->firstname;?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php }
  ?>
```

Comment: @DS9 where can i place this code, can u tell me please? - thanks in advance

Comment: @Alejo_Blue end the line in the function.php file..!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `<tr>` inside your foreach loop, and add `.` concatenation operator in your line, you need also try this :

- You need to wrap `<td></td>` inside `<tr></tr>` in foreach loop
- You need to add `.` concatenation operator in line that contains firstname variable.
- If you have duplicate values, then add this parameter  `ARRAY_A`  to your query

  `$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM myTable",ARRAY_A );`.

  ```
   <table border="1">
       <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Points</th>
       </tr>

         <?php
           global $wpdb;
           $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM myTable" );
           foreach ( $result as $print )   {
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td>' . $print->firstname .'</td>';
                     echo '<td>' . $print->lastname  .'</td>';
                     echo '<td>' . $print->points    .'</td>';
             echo '</tr>';
               }
         ?>

   </table>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `.` in `echo '<td>' $print->firstname.'</td>';`

Try this

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;
  $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM myTable" );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {

      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>' . $print->firstname.'</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $print->lastname.'</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $print->points.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM myTable" , ARRAY_A); //get result as associative array
```

Then the usual cycle:

```
//spare memory
$count = count($result);
//fastest way to perform the cycle
for ($i = $count; $i--;) {
   echo '<td>'. $print[$i]['firstname'].'</td>';
}
```