# Good solution for displaying a SQL query on a WordPress site

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a wordpress site that I have uploaded a few custom SQL tables via phpMyAdmin. I'm trying to find a good way of displaying custom queries on my wordpress page. I've tried using WP_Datatables, but have run into too many problems with it.

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin recommendation, or are looking to build your own wp_query and work with PHP + HTML/CSS? Also, can you elaborate on what this plugin does/does not do that causes you to rule it out?

Answer (score 2):

There are some answers to similar questions already on SO; it's a good idea to search first, i.e. [Display data from database inside <table> using wordpress $wpdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824461/display-data-from-database-inside-table-using-wordpress-wpdb)

But basically use the WordPress database abstraction layer `wpdb`

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/ for how to use it and see examples, such as below:

```
// 1st Method - Declaring $wpdb as global and using it to
  execute an SQL query statement that returns a PHP object

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );

// 2nd Method - Utilizing the $GLOBALS superglobal.
Does not require global keyword ( but may not be best practice )

$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );
```

> The $wpdb object is not limited to the default tables created by
> WordPress; it can be used to read data from any table in the WordPress
> database (such as custom plugin tables). For example to SELECT some
> information from a custom table called "mytable", you can do the
> following.

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
```